# Call JADE Agent from Java Servlets?

Tags: java, servlets, agents-jade

Can any one please tell me how would I call JADE Agent from Java Servlet ?  Should I use JADEGatewayAgent ?

Answer (score 3):

Yes, you need to use the [JadeGateway](http://jade.tilab.com/doc/api/jade/wrapper/gateway/JadeGateway.html) class. Here is nice [tutorial](http://jade.cselt.it/doc/tutorials/JadeGateway.pdf)

The source code can be downloaded from [here](http://people.inf.elte.hu/kelemen/jade/JadeGateWaySimple_source.zip) , except for some minor configuration in eclipse the app should be working right away.

Comment: I configure the above code but it shows me exception i.e. jade.core.ProfileException: Cannot detect Main Container, jade.wrapper.ControllerException: JADE startup failed. can you solve my problem?

Comment: I could not find source code, the link does n't  work, is there any other link?